# How do I set wistia bind code with a variable for video ID?

Tags: javascript, wistia

This is wistia api code for binding to the video and firing actions at certain points in the video. I'm trying to use a variable to specify the id of the video to bind to but doesn't seem to work:

```
wistiaid = "pebjeod7h";
firetime = 15;
fired = false;

window._wq = window._wq || [];

_wq.push({
    wistiaid: function(video) {
        video.bind("secondchange", function(s) {

                if (s >= firetime && !fired) {
                    console.log("fired");
                    fired=true;
                    jQuery("#nextvideo").show();

                }

        });
    }
});
```

If I hardcode the id of the video like this it works fine:

```
_wq.push({
  "pebjeod7h": function(video) {
```

but want to use a variable for better abstraction and re-useability

```
_wq.push({
    wistiaid: function(video) {
```

Appreciate the help...

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the documentation isn't better. It took me a long time to figure this out.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window._wq = window._wq || [];
    var videoId = "jkh234kjh234bs";
    var pushObj = {};
    pushObj[videoId] = function (video) {
        console.log("Found handle to the video", video);
        video.bind("secondchange", function (s) {
            var secondsWatched = video.secondsWatched();
            if (secondsWatched > 0) {
                console.log('Cursor is at ' + s + ' seconds; ' + secondsWatched + ' unique seconds have been watched.');
            }
        });
    };
    _wq.push(pushObj);
});
```